# Aceder a uma query string e adicionar o valor a um input vindo de um iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, querystring

Tenho uma página que contem um iframe com um formulário, gostava de conseguir aceder a uma query string da página principal e adicionar esse valor a um input hidden que está no iframe.

É possivel?

Obrigado

Comment: Essa iframe está no mesmo dominio que a página principal?

Comment: Sim está, num pasta à parte mas no mesmo domnio